# section index overlaps the search bar (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

```
import UIKit

class orderPo: UITableViewController{
var sections : [(index: Int, length :Int, title: String)] = Array()
var array = ["Moscow", "@Saint Petersburg", "Novosibirsk", "Novosibirsk", "Nizhny Novgorod", "Samara", "Omsk", "Kiyv", "Odessa", "@Donetsk", "Harkiv", "Lviv", "Uzhgorod", "Zhytomyr", "Luhansk", "Mikolayv", "Kherson", "Germany", "Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich", "Cologne", "Frankfurt", "Stuttgart", "Düsseldorf", "Dortmund", "Essen", "Bremen", "Abilene", "Akron", "Albuquerque", "Alexandria", "Allentown", "Amarillo", "Anaheim", "Anchorage", "Ann Arbor", "Antioch", "Arlington", "Arvada", "Athens", "Atlanta", "Augusta", "Aurora", "Austin", "Bakersfield", "Baltimore", "Baton Rouge", "Beaumont", "Bellevue", "Berkeley", "Billings", "Birmingham", "Boise", "Boston", "Boulder", "Bridgeport", "Broken Arrow", "Brownsville", "Buffalo", "Burbank", "Cambridge", "Cape Coral", "Carlsbad", "Carrollton", "Cary", "Cedar Rapids", "Centennial", "Chandler", "Charleston", "Charlotte", "Chattanooga", "Chesapeake", "Chicago", "Chula Vista", "Cincinnati", "Clarksville", "Clearwater", "Cleveland", "College Station", "Colorado Springs", "Columbia", "Columbus", "Concord", "Coral Springs", "Corona", "Corpus Christi", "Costa Mesa", "Dallas", "Daly City", "Davenport", "Dayton", "Denton", "Denver", "Des Moines", "Detroit", "Downey", "Durham", "Edison", "El Cajon", "El Monte", "El Paso", "Elgin", "Elizabeth", "Elk Grove", "Erie", "Escondido", "Eugene", "Evansville", "Everett", "Fairfield", "Fargo", "Fayetteville", "Fontana", "Fort Collins", "Fort Lauderdale", "Fort Wayne", "Fort Worth", "Fremont", "Fresno", "Frisco", "Fullerton", "Gainesville", "Garden Grove", "Garland", "Gilbert", "Glendale", "Grand Prairie", "Grand Rapids", "Green Bay", "Greensboro", "Gresham", "Hampton", "Hartford", "Hayward", "Henderson", "Hialeah", "High Point", "Hollywood", "Honolulu", "Houston", "Huntington Beach", "Huntsville", "Independence", "Indianapolis", "Inglewood", "Irvine", "Irving", "Jackson", "Jacksonville", "Jersey City", "Joliet", "Kansas City", "Kent", "Killeen", "Knoxville", "Lafayette", "Lakeland", "Lakewood", "Lancaster", "Lansing", "Laredo", "Las Cruces", "Las Vegas", "Lewisville", "Lexington", "Lincoln", "Little Rock", "Long Beach", "Los Angeles", "Louisville", "Lowell", "Lubbock", "Madison", "Manchester", "McAllen", "McKinney", "Memphis", "Mesa", "Mesquite", "Miami", "Miami Gardens", "Midland", "Milwaukee", "Minneapolis", "Miramar", "Mobile", "Modesto", "Montgomery", "Moreno Valley", "Murfreesboro", "Murrieta", "Naperville", "Nashville", "New Haven", "New Orleans", "New York", "Newark", "Newport News", "Norfolk", "Norman", "North Charleston", "North Las Vegas", "Norwalk", "Oakland", "Oceanside", "Oklahoma City", "Olathe", "Omaha", "Ontario", "Orange", "Orlando", "Overland Park", "Oxnard", "Palm Bay", "Palmdale", "Pasadena", "Paterson", "Pearland", "Pembroke Pines", "Peoria", "Peoria", "Philadelphia", "Phoenix", "Pittsburgh", "Plano", "Pomona", "Pompano Beach", "Port St. Lucie", "Portland", "Providence", "Provo", "Pueblo", "Raleigh", "Rancho Cucamonga", "Reno", "Rialto", "Richardson", "Richmond", "Riverside", "Rochester", "Rockford", "Roseville", "Round Rock", "Sacramento", "Saint Paul", "Salem", "Salinas", "Salt Lake City", "San Antonio", "San Bernardino", "San Diego", "San Francisco", "San Jose", "San Mateo", "Santa Ana", "Santa Clara", "Santa Clarita", "Santa Maria", "Santa Rosa", "Savannah", "Scottsdale", "Seattle", "Shreveport", "Simi Valley", "Sioux Falls", "South Bend", "Spokane", "Springfield", "St. Louis", "St. Petersburg", "Stamford", "Sterling Heights", "Stockton", "Sunnyvale", "Surprise", "Syracuse", "Tacoma", "Tallahassee", "Tampa", "Temecula", "Tempe", "Thornton", "Thousand Oaks", "Toledo", "Topeka", "Torrance", "Tucson", "Tulsa", "Tyler", "Vallejo", "Vancouver", "Ventura", "Victorville", "Virginia Beach", "Visalia", "Waco", "Warren", "Washington", "Waterbury", "West Covina", "West Jordan", "West Palm Beach", "West Valley City", "Westminster", "Wichita", "Wichita Falls", "Wilmington", "Winston–Salem", "Woodbridge", "Worcester", "Yonkers", "York"]
var filterArray :[String] = []

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All"){
    filterArray = array.filter{ text in return text.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
}
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        sections = []
        filterArray.sortInPlace { $0 < $1 } // sort by alphabetic
        var index = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < filterArray.count; i++ ) {
            let commonPrefix = filterArray[i].commonPrefixWithString(filterArray[index], options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            if (commonPrefix.isEmpty) {
                let string = filterArray[index].uppercaseString;
                let firstCharacter = string[string.startIndex]
                let title = "\(firstCharacter)"
                let newSection = (index: index, length: i - index, title: title)
                sections.append(newSection)
                index = i;
            }

        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
override func viewDidLoad() {


    array.sortInPlace { $0 < $1 } // sort by alphabetic
    var index = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.count; i++ ) {
        let commonPrefix = array[i].commonPrefixWithString(array[index], options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        if (commonPrefix.isEmpty) {
            let string = array[index].uppercaseString;
            let firstCharacter = string[string.startIndex]
            let title = "\(firstCharacter)"
            let newSection = (index: index, length: i - index, title: title)
            sections.append(newSection)
            index = i;
        }
        }

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return sections.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return sections[section].length

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
    cell.textLabel?.text = filterArray[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]
    }
    else{
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {

    return sections[section].title

}


override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return sections.map { $0.title }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {

    return index

}


}

extension orderPo:UISearchResultsUpdating{
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
}
```

How to set the height of the section index bar? it overlaps the search bar right now. it covers the search bar. How to make the section index bar just below the search bar. How to do that? Any helps would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The SearchController is not designed to support a ScopeBar. It is a controller that handles simple use cases for you. If you need a scope bar you should add a UISearchBar component in your storyboard and handle the search by implementing its delegate functions.